# How can I set paragraph background color the same width as the text?

Tags: html

How can I set the paragraph background color the same width as the text?

I mean, whith this:

```
<div><p style="background:skyblue">What a background</p></div>
```

I have this:
[image]

But I want this:
[image]

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082121/background-color-to-be-the-same-height-and-width-as-the-text-or-link) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737771/how-can-i-make-the-background-of-an-li-the-same-length-as-the-text-in-it) similar posts but doesn't apply for me, because on my case, I just have this paragraph inside a div.

Comment: display:inline-block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to turn the element in question from `display: block` (the default for a `<p>`), to `display: inline-block`:

```css
p {
  background: skyblue;
}

.tight-background {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text
</p>
<p class="tight-background">
  Text 2
</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: O: so simple, ty.